Dotfuscator Community Edition and VS2022 - errors with "Shelf Check" issues even though I'm not using that check
I've been using Dotfuscator for years.  Nothing has changed, but now when I try to run it, I get:
Could not find a version of the Shelf Life Check library that is runtime compatible with all input assemblies.  Highest detected runtime version is v4.0.30319.
(my exe is DotNet 4.7.2 - not sure if they are referring to my runtime or their own?)
I've gone back to an old version of everything, which ran through Dotfuscator fine previously, and get the same result.  I'm not using the Shelf Life check, but am using the Debugging Check and Tamper Check.  If I delete BOTH of these (or disable checks) then it works.
I'm running 6.5.3+7f0b0a9d18.  From their website I downloaded the latest (but older) version - DotfuscatorCE_6.3.0+8b29d6f4a2.vsix - but it fails to install - the error log shows Invalid Certificate (humerously I think it fails the Shelf Life check LOL):
26/05/2024 11:59:43 -      [Subject]       : CN="PreEmptive Solutions, LLC.", O="PreEmptive Solutions, LLC.", STREET=767 Beta Drive, L=CLEVELAND, S=Ohio, PostalCode=44143, C=US
26/05/2024 11:59:43 -      [Issuer]        : CN=Sectigo RSA Code Signing CA, O=Sectigo Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
26/05/2024 11:59:43 -      [Serial Number] : 00F003BAA0FB3F9EBC2BD20AAAC0C47E43
26/05/2024 11:59:43 -      [Not Before]    : 07/02/2020 00:00:00
26/05/2024 11:59:43 -      [Not After]     : 07/05/2023 00:59:59
26/05/2024 11:59:43 -      [Thumbprint]    : 26C62F9DBD462187A756D0C1A18AD814E42C8456
Is Dotfuscator CE not a thing any more?  I've tried reporting to them but they don't have a way to do so for Community Edition.
Does anyone have any ideas?  Or are there more modern alternatives to Dotfuscator? (free or cheap.... this is just a sideline for me).
I've tried old version of my code known to work, updating Dotfuscator but failed, reaching out to PreEmptive and I tried googling it with no helpful results.  I tried updating VS2022 to the latest and I tried rebooting.  I'm not sure what else I can try.
Thanks in advance.
